# what is the wrong in my code it showing error " Invalid left-hand side in assignment "?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

it is showing error Invalid left-hand side in assignment? what is wrong in this code can any once help ?

Comment: Don't submit code in a image- it makes it harder for other users to run that code, or use it in an answer. See [the formatting guide](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: remove a==1 and similar. it is not needed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have expressions returning `true`, which you then attempt to assign values.

What you meant to do is:

```
var a = document.getElementById('number').value; 
switch (+a){
    case 1 : alert('enter one'); break;
    case 2 : alert('enter two'); break;
    case 3 : alert('enter three'); break;
    case 4 : alert('enter four'); break;
}
```

The switch statement handles the comparisons for you. `case 1` is the case where a is equal to 1.

Also, you want to get the element with the id "number", and instead of `switch(a)`, you want `switch(+a)`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your JavaScript. Syntax for Switch case is wrong. This is how it should be:

```
switch(a) {
    case 1: alert("enter one");break;
    case 2: alert("enter two");break;
    case 3:  alert("enter three");break;
    case 4:  alert("enter four");break;
}
```

[JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) documentation

Comment: @popoornimapuligadda replace your switch case code with above code.